# What do the Visual Studio margin colors mean?

Tags: visual-studio

I noticed that Visual Studio colors a few pixel wide area in the margin, to the right of the area where you place breakpoints. What do these colors mean?

Comment: **See also:** [Green Bars in Visual Studio 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2823327/2392157) – This question has worse title, but more accurate answers.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Colours as follows:

- **No colour** = Line unchanged since you opened the file
- **Green** = Line changed since you opened the file, but saved
- **Yellow** = Line changed since you last saved
- **Blue** = Line changed and saved, then reverted back by undoing.

To see the entire list of colours, go to `Tools`>`Options`>`Environment`>`Fonts and Colors`.

Answer (score 0):

This is an indication of what has been edited. Green means unchanged since last build (save technically, but files are saved every time the project is built), yellow means edited. No color means that the file is unchanged since opening the file.

Comment: This is incorrect. Green means unchanged since last *save*, not since last build.

Comment: While technically true, files are saved everytime they are built. You do have a point though.

Comment: Worth mentioning that no color means original code (when you opened the file)

Comment: Actually, files aren't necessarily saved every time you build. That's the default, but it's configurable in Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Build and Run.

Comment: So it has nothing (directly) to do with version control (git)? If so I can see this get very confusing..