# Green Bars in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I am wondering what these greens things are in Visual Studio 2010. What are they for? They look pretty random but of course they have to have some meaning. Can any one tell me?

At first glance they don't mean any thing to me.

**Picture 1:**

[image: Image 1]

**Picture 2:**

[image: Image 2]

**Edit:**

They show saved changed content during the document open. Once you close the document they disappear.

Comment: Hmm in Visual Studio 2017 for me: Green means saved, but not Committed to git.

Answer (score 150, accepted):

They show lines that you have changed.

See [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/zainnab/archive/2010/04/14/track-changes-in-the-editor-vstipedit0048.aspx) for more details and a table showing what the different colours mean:

```
+-----------+------------------------------+-------------------------+
| Marker    |     Different from           |    Different from file  |
|  colour   |       file saved on disk?    |      that was opened?   |
+-----------+------------------------------+-------------------------+
| Nothing   |        No                    |       No                |
| Yellow    |        Yes                   |       Yes               |
| Green     |        No                    |       Yes               |
| Orange    |        Yes                   |       No                |
+-----------+------------------------------+-------------------------+
```

Edit: `Blue` indicates that the line was changed, saved and then reverted by undoing.
To see the entire list of colour schemes, go to `Tools`>`Opitons`>`Environment`>`Fonts and Colors`.(or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>.then type "Fonts and Colors")

Comment: More than I was expecting. Thanks for the link. It is pretty useful.

Comment: "Different from file that was opened" should be "modified since file was opened". Also I wish that they had a mouse-over explaining this.

Comment: +1 for a tooltip explaining what the colored bands mean.  Totally predictable that a lot of people would have no clue what the colors mean, especially green which is unusual to say the least.

Answer (score 19):

**Yellow** - source code that has been changed since you opened the file, and that *hasn't* been saved.

**Green** - source code that has been changed since you opened the file, and that *has* been saved.

Answer (score 13):

IN SUMMARY...

Start out blank.

Make a change = Yellow.

Save the change = Green.

Undo = Orange.

Change the line again = Yellow.

Answer (score 11):

#### Visual Studio editor margin can also show light blue bars. But it is only substitution of orange color in some dark themes.

In addition to other answers, please note that there is **blue instead of orange** in dark themes:

#### Light themes

[image]

#### Dark themes

(**orange** color is represented as **light blue**)

[image]

#### Customization

Using [Visual Studio Color Theme Editor](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/20cd93a2-c435-4d00-a797-499f16402378) plugin from the Microsoft, you can focus on the following 3 items:

[image]

The same plugin is available also for more recent versions of Visual Studio, for example
[Visual Studio 2015 Color Theme Editor](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6f4b51b6-5c6b-4a81-9cb5-f2daa560430b).

Answer (score 5):

This is edited lines of text after last save

or/and

Lines of code edited by Edit->Advanced->Format Document. It formats code (spaces, line breaks, etc) corresponding VS settings for current file's language

Answer (score 1):

Those indicate where the source code has been changed.