# How to remove green line near breakpoint in visual studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have no clue what this line means, how it got there, or how to remove it. [image: damn green line]

Comment: Did you just edit that line and save the file? Those are change indicators. Refer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823327/green-bars-in-visual-studio-2010

Comment: possible duplicate of [Green Bars in Visual Studio 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823327/green-bars-in-visual-studio-2010)

Comment: OMG how big is your monitor?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The colored lines on the side of the Visual Studio text editor display lines that have changed since open and are unsaved (yellow) or saved (green).

It's a handy way to quickly tell what changes you've made to the file at a glance. However if you want to turn it off you can toggle it by going to `Tools` -> `Options` -> `Text Editor` and unchecking `Track Changes`.

[image: Turn off the "Track Changes" option for the "Text Editor" under Options]

Answer (score 1):

That marker saves the changes that have been made to your working directory since you last opened visual studio. I find this feature quite useful, especially when working with a team. You can turn them off from preferences if you really hate them, but I would recommend using them because they will save you time in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

If you've upgraded to VS2022 the colours of these lines have changed to be much darker, which can fool you into feeling like they're a new feature (I certainly was!).

You can set the colours back in the `Fonts and Colors` settings.  VS2019 colours are listed here:

- Track Changes before save - `RGB 108,226,108`
- Track Changes after save - `RGB 255,238,98`

[image: Fonts and Colors Settings]