# How to see(mark) lines, that are changed comparing to the project repo, in emacs?

Tags: version-control, emacs

Is there any way to current working copy modifications in-place by marking somehow all modified lines. For example NetBeans has the following feature:
[image]

In MSVC also, smth like this (not for VCS, but it looks alike):
[Green Bars in Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823327/green-bars-in-visual-studio-2010)

I use vc-mode in Emacs to work with my versioned project. It can compute the full diff ( vc-diff) but it is inconvinient: to browse the diff separately. I want, to know all changed lines, during file-editing sesstion. Is it implemented in some version-control plugin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [diff-hl](https://github.com/dgutov/diff-hl) extension does this in a VCS-agnostic way. There also exist other tools like [git-gutter](https://github.com/syohex/emacs-git-gutter) which are more focused on a specific VCS.

Comment: Yes, that is a drawback for diff-hl. However, git-gutter does work in the console and might be an option for you if you use git.