# How to get rid of green warning line in VS2010 editor?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

How can I hide the green warning line which VS2010 is suggesting?

Some of them just doesn't make sense. I tried go to options but no luck so far.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean but is this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823327/green-bars-in-visual-studio-2010 what you are looking for?

Comment: it *always* makes sence. better get rid of the issues that causing green line

Comment: The green underlines will not cause any problems. Just ignore them if you don't want to make the change suggested.

Comment: It looks mostly happening on Devexpress Controls

Comment: Thx Lucas not those Vertical ones,the one thats Underline

Comment: Sometimes in Codebehind too for example DataContext.RevisionHistories.Where(n => n.RevisionID == revisionid).FirstOrDefault(); which says "Replace with single call to FirstOrDefault(...) "

Comment: @YuriyGalanter Nope. It certainly does not make sense in some cases, for example in complex macro structures, when `module` is defined as `: public IMyInterface` and a class is declared as `class MyModule module {};`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't honestly suggest this, but since you asked...

From the menu, `Tools`, `Options`. Then select **Environment**, **Fonts and Colors** and under **Display Items** choose `Warning` and change the item foreground to match the item background (typically white)

[image]