# C# Visual Studio 2013 suppress 'Class is never instantiated'

Tags: c#, suppress-warnings

I have a web api project which accepts HttpPost communications.

The controller's methods always accepting a single validated object.

For example:

```
public sealed class NumbersRequest
{
    [NumberOne]
    public string Number1 { get; set; }

    [NumberTwo]
    public string Number2 { get; set; }
}
```

Since I never declare `NumbersRequest req = new NumbersRequest()` and they only serve as a request object, Im getting the

> class is never instantiated

How can I suppress the warning? (its more like a green underline..)
Maybe something with annontations?

Thanks.

Comment: What is giving that warning? Code analysis?

Comment: its not an actually a compiler warning, like these that you see near the Errors. but its bugging me. it paints it in a green line.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17998471/11683 is probably not what you want, but may be an option.

Comment: @GSerg thats like the biggest walk-around i've ever seen :).
I want to keep getting these warnings, not just ignore them. speficially on my httpRequest objects i want to ignore it.

Comment: This is most likely ReSharper. You can either ask ReSharper in a settings file (global or tied to your solution) to stop bugging you about these things *overall*, or you can pull in the ReSharper annotations and annotate the type with the `[PublicAPI]` attribute.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen green line still apears and so as the warning

Comment: Then you have `[ImplicitlyUsed]`, either one of them *should* make ReSharper silent about the type.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen [UsedImplicitly] did the trick. want to post as an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This looks like a ReSharper warning](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/ReSharper/Class+'Name'+is+never+instantiated) and as such you can ask ReSharper to be silent about these things.

You can either configure ReSharper to stop complaining about this overall, you do this simply by hitting Alt+Enter on the squiggly in question and use the bottom menu item that usually allows you to configure the inspection severity.

You can opt to save this in your global settings, which means it will affect every project you open from now on, or you can save it to a team-shared settings file which you can then check into source control alongside your project, to make it only count for this one solution.

Now, if you want to keep the warning *overall* but ask it to stop complaining about one or more particular types, methods, properties or the likes, you can use the attributes that ReSharper provides.

You have several ways of bringing these attributes into your project:

1. Add a reference to the Nuget package "JetBrains ReSharper annotations"
2. Use the options dialog for ReSharper and find the page where it allows you to grab a copy of the source for those attributes onto the clipboard, then simply paste this into a file in your project.
3. Define just the one or two attributes you want, even in your own namespace (which you then have to tell ReSharper about)

The recommended way is option 1, use the nuget package.

Assuming you now have the attributes available you can use either `PublicAPIAttribute` or the `UsedImplicitlyAttribute`.

Either one *should* suffice but they may have different connotations. Since you're flagging objects being transferred to or from clients I would go with the `PublicAPIAttribute` first.

---

Since you say in a comment that the `PublicAPIAttribute` didn't work but `UsedImplicitlyAttribute` did then I guess they *do* have different meanings.

Comment: As a general tip, if you're using ReSharper and want to get the most out of the product you *really* should look at the attributes that can tell ReSharper more about your code than it can figure out on its own. There are some *really* useful attributes in there. In particular, look at the `NotNullAttribute` and `CanBeNullAttribute` and start tagging **everything** with them appropriately, then start taking care of all the squigglies that ReSharper shows in your code. You can thank me later. You also have `Item****` versions of the same for tagging elements in collections.