# What the Green band in code editor Visual Studio 2013 means?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I'm reading a VB.NET code file that has a green band beside the line code. See this snapshot:

[image]

I also add that this method is an asynchronous method (its signature is shown in the snapshot).

Is it a warning suppression?

Thanks in advance for your help!

P.S.: Another important point is that `ReturnValue` y a synchronous `Sub`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Green Bars in Visual Studio 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823327/green-bars-in-visual-studio-2010)

Comment: @Neolisk, the question you mentioned have images that don't load (they are hosted in an external image hosting service, instead in SO.)

Comment: Yeah, I know, just linked a canonical/full answer. It also has information about orange bars, and an official reference.

Comment: @Neolisk I've fixed the broken links, so we should still close this as a duplicate.

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå: How did you do that? Upload your own screenshots? Just my curiosity... :)

Comment: @Neolisk I pasted the [original links](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8e9a5945-dede-4bce-8d3e-50d828c4ba6c/view-source) into the [Wayback Machine](http://archive.org/web/) and downloaded the original images.

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå: That was pretty cool, I didn't know such thing existed. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bands tell you information about your current session in visual studio.

When you *edit* lines, you'll get a yellow band shown next to them.

When you *save* the file, the band turns green.

The bands will not be retained if you close and re-open the file.

So from your screenshot, I can tell that you've edited line 329 (maybe added it) during your current session and that that change has been saved to disk.

Comment: Reference: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/04/14/track-changes-in-the-editor-vstipedit0048.aspx