# What are these boxes and how do I remove them?

Tags: visual-studio

I have a blue box and a green line next to line numbers in studio. What are these and how can I get rid of them?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blue box on the left is a bookmark. To toggle (turn on and off) a bookmark, place a cursor on the line and press `Ctrl+F2` (or in menu Edit > Bookmarks > Toggle Bookmark). Bookmarks are useful tool. With `F2` you can quickly jump to the next one.

Green bar (also yellow, and also orange in VS2010) is visual indicator that that line has been changed. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2823327/395718). The feature is useful, and you get used to it after a while, and think nothing of it. If you want to disable this feature go to menu Tools > Options > Text Editor > General and uncheck "Track changes".