# Blue lines in Visual Studio editor margin

Tags: visual-studio

I've been seeing these blue lines in the margin when using Visual Studio:

[image]
[image]

I know the yellow and green lines indicate edits but can't find anything on the blue lines.

Does anyone know what they mean?

Comment: Those lines have been edited, yellow is unsaved row.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Green Bars in Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823327/green-bars-in-visual-studio-2010)

Comment: Btw, to remove these indicators (v1.73.1) simply `Settings` -> `Features` -> `Source Control` -> `Diff Decorations`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visual Studio uses three colours to track changes; **yellow** (*a change before saving*), **green** (*a change after saving*) and **orange** (*a reverted change*).

See `Tools > Options > Fonts and Colors > Track Changes` to see these colors.

In dark visual themes, the orange is replaced with **blue**.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2823327/254882) (and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36217671/254882)) for more details.