# What do the colored marks mean in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: ide, visual-studio-code

I'm using Visual Studio Code (Version 1.15). I've attached a screenshot of this IDE which contains three type of marks on the left side of the editor window. What do these marks mean exactly?

[image: Screenshot of Visual Studio Code IDE]

Comment: you might want to check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/973598/what-do-the-visual-studio-margin-colors-mean

Comment: and this link too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44129996/blue-lines-in-visual-studio-editor-margin where orange line is replaced with blue

Comment: Thanks. Actually I'm using Visual Studio Code(a free IDE released by Microsoft) which is a different from Visual Studio.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These marks are called [gutter indicators](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/versioncontrol#_gutter-indicators).

> - A red triangle indicates where lines have been deleted
> - A green bar indicates new added lines
> - A blue bar indicates modified lines